# Where can I find the full names for the industry group shortcodes from Linkedin?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have used the Linkedin industry list ( https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/reference/industry-codes ) for a survey.

Now that the survey is over I want to downsize the whole industries to just the groups which are given on the website.

Most codes can easily be assigned to the industry group, but some names are rather ambiguous and I was hoping someone might be able to help me assign all codes to the correct full names of the industry groups.
e.g.: hlth - healthcare, cons - construction, tran - transportation, etc.
The codes I find most ambiguous are man, corp, rec and org.

I would be very happy if anyone could either refer me to a link where I can find all full names or just help me assign those few codes to their full names.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Not a coding question. Please ask this in superuser.

Comment: @SRIDHARAN, you are absolutely right my friend and thank you for the hint with superuser. I just posted it there as well, but I was actually referred to ask this question here by someone of the support team from Linkedin, as they said SO would be the most likely point of interaction with those who know about these shortcodes

Comment: @SRIDHARAN Websites such as Linkedin are off topic on [su], as are "find me *something*" questions.

Comment: @Mokubai would you have any idea where I might be able to get an answer for this question? As mentioned, I was referred to ask here by the Linkedin Support, then I was asked by SRIDHARAN to post it on Super user, now it got deleted there. What am I supposed to do?